# How to convert username to hyperlink in comment reply similar to StackExchange?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, comments

Is there any contributed module or usable functionality which is somewhat similar to StackExchange reply comment, where when we add username with "`@`" sign, it notifies user. However in my case I would like to convert them into users profile page hyperlink.

For example, if user added in reply `@foobar`, if username with `foobar` exists will be converted in hyperlink to foobar profile page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [Mentions](https://www.drupal.org/project/mentions) module:

> The Mentions module offers Twitter like functionality, recording all references to a user's username - using the [@username] or [@#uid] filter format - from various locations, providing a centralized page to track all mentions (via the Views module).

Comment: Thanks ton @AjitS, how did you search it, I was not able to find it on drupal :)

Comment: I had used it in one of the projects. I used Google to find it the last time :)